# Como crear una consulta en Oracle de select

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, oracle-sqldeveloper

Espero me puedan orientar, me dejaron una consulta en oracle donde al poner el select aparte de consultar todos los datos de la tabla tambien pueda escoger uno en especifico que quiera ver.Mi consulta esta en un paquete de oracle y luego lo ejecuto pero no entiendo mucho como podria usarlo para ver todos los datos de la tabla y dependiendo lo que necesite en codigo tomar por ejemplo el ID.

Es un stored procedure espero me puedan orientar.

```
-- Procedimiento almacenado de obtener datos de la tabla usuarios
PROCEDURE sp_Obtener ( e_disp IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
  IS
  BEGIN
  OPEN e_disp  for SELECT *
  FROM USUARIOS
  ORDER BY ID ASC;
END;
```

Comment: Que haz intentado?, recuerda agregar un intento verificable para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida, esta comunidad esta para apoyar siempre y cuando se vea el intento e investigación del autor de la pregunta. Ahora, es una consulta o un procedimiento el que necesitas, se mas especifica.

Comment: Justo di el stored no solo pregunto para que me den la respuesta, pero solo explique a como entendi cuando realmente no entendia a que se referian, igual ya lo tengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione así por si no me entendieron mucho.

```
PROCEDURE sp_Obtener (  pID VARCHAR2, pNAME VARCHAR2, e_disp IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  IS
  BEGIN
  OPEN e_disp  for 
  SELECT ID,NAME,PATERNAL,MATERNAL,PHONE
   FROM USUARIOS
   WHERE ID = NVL(pID,ID) AND 
   NAME = NVL(pNAME,NAME)
   ORDER BY ID ASC
   --AND
   --PATERNAL = NVL('',PATERNAL) AND
   --MATERNAL = NVL('',MATERNAL) AND
   --PHONE = NVL('',PHONE)
   ;
END;
```